# ConstraintLayout InflateException: <Can't convert value at index..> & <For input string..>

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, android-constraintlayout

Using a `ConstraintLayout` and setting all four `layout_constraint..` throws the following unhandled exception:

`Android.Views.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Can't convert value at index 19 to dimension: type=0x10`

And by removing the bottom constraint and setting any ratio in the `LinearLayout` this time throws this unhandled exception:

`Android.Views.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: For input string: "H,16:9"`

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
  <LinearLayout
      android:orientation="vertical"
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="0dp"
      android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
      android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
      android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
      android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
      app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="H,16:9">
```

This same exact xml works in Android Studio but not in Xamarin. Is this a bug or am i missing something?

Note: I'm using the `Xamarin.Android.Support.Constraint.Layout` package version `1.0.2.2` which is the latest stable version.

Comment: It is not a bug, it works on my side. Try clean, rebuild. Or delete the bin/obj, restart VS.

Comment: @JoeLv-MSFT Hmm! Removing both bin and obj did actually work. Wasted 4 days of digging for nothing.

Comment: @JoeLv-MSFT Oh yes please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please delete the bin/obj folder, and rebuild. Sometimes the VS compiler will make some mistakes.